# for loop running time analysis java

Tags: java, big-o

**For all of these I have to find out the running time.**

1.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i+=2 )
    sum++;
```

2.

```
for ( int i = 1; i < n; i*=2 )
    sum++
```

3.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        sum++;
```

4.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    sum++
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    sum++
// The above are two loops one after the other, NOT nested
```

5.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++ )
    sum++
```

6.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n*n; i++ )
    sum++;
```

7.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < n*n; j++ )
        sum++;
```

8.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    for ( int j = 0; j < 10000; j++ )
        sum++;
```

---

For the first one I got O(n) and the fourth one I got O(n^2). Are these correct? And how do I do the others? I am really confused with the second one.

Answer can be expressed in big O or big theta.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you count the number of operations in terms of `n`.

E.g.:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i+=2 )
    sum++;
```

`sum++` is 1 operation, and you loop `n/2` times.  Thus, this code does `n/2` operations.  Thus, big O is `O(n/2) = O(n)` (you can throw out the constant factor of `1/2`).

For the other problems, simply do the same thing (count the number of times `sum++` is executed, then simplify by throwing out constants).

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you quickly explain the second one? I'm still confused about how many times that loop would run.

Comment: `i` doubles each time.  So if you double `n`, you loop 1 more time.

Answer (score 2):

A formal,  but tedious, methodology to come up with your loops order of growth complexity, using Sigma notation (Discrete Mathematics).

```
1. Linear
```

[image]

```
2. Logarithmic
```

[image]

```
3. Nested Independent Loops
```

[image]

```
4. Independent Loops
```

[image]

```
5. Linear
```

[image]

```
6. Quadratic
```

[image]

```
7. Independent Nested Loops
```

[image]

```
8. Independent Nested Loops
```

[image]